What durable material can I use to repair a window well?
I have a basement / below grade glass block window through which our dryer vents, into an exterior window well. The wood framing on both sides (inside and outside), mostly on the bottom of the glass blocks, has rotted. I am not willing to replace the glass block but I need to reframe the inside and outside of the glass blocks, in some sort of moisture proof way. I do not believe we get any significant water (from rain, flooding, ground water or otherwise) in the window well but obviously there is moisture there.
Looking for suggestions as to either type of wood to use or another product to use instead of wood that can handle some moisture without rotting (is there a composite material of any kind?). And on the outside the framing will need to be "re-connected" to the masonry/foundation of the house/window well.



I can think of three viable options.

Pressure-treated lumber. This is what's used in new home situations, and it's probably what was in your home unless it was built more than 50 years ago. A solid lumber box anchored to the foundation with concrete screws and with silicone or foam to fill gaps should do well.

Solid synthetic lumber, such as original Trex decking. Since this isn't a structural situation it would work fine as a filler material. You'd probably want to pilot and screw it together. Again, use concrete screws and sealants.

Masonry. You could purchase something like concrete block wall cap and mortar it in place like brick. Most seems to be 2 inches thick, so you'd need room for that plus mortar, which you'd point into the joints.



Most solutions will be temporary for maximum dozen or so years. There will be no big difference if You use wood or other material for framing, as long you use proper outdoor paint for lining.
If possible add pipe/duct from window to outside of well, with some kind of condensate drain, to move hot steam as far as possible.
I hope You have right drainage of rainwater in well.
Edit after pictures added:
Yes. Hot steam goes up, condensate on frame do damages and then droplets do damage on bottom. Repainting every 2-3 years will help a little but move steam as far as possible from window is best solution.

I disagree that paint is a substitute for pressure-treated lumber. Painted wood still gets wet internally if moisture is present, and it rots much more quickly.
